# Why are the Niqqud different for the name of God sometimes?

Tags: hebrew, tanach, shemos-sacred-names, mesorah-tradition, vowels-nekudot

Through my research of the Tanakh, I have observed that the tetragrammaton appears with varying niqqud in different locations. Additionally, I have noted that the niqqud used may differ but produce a similar sound, while in certain cases, the niqqud on the "He" letter is absent without contradiction to other pronunciations. In general, there appear to be two common spellings, one using the vowels E, O, and A, and the other employing E, O, and I.

My findings are based on several sources, namely Genesis 2:4, Genesis 3:14, Judges 16:28, Genesis 15:2, 1 Kings 2:26, and Ezekiel 24:24. I have developed two hypotheses to explain these observations. One possibility is that the alternative spellings with the vowel ending in "I," as opposed to "A," could indicate a possessive form of the name of God. Alternatively, it is plausible that the Masoretes intentionally employed these inconsistencies to prevent readers from accurately pronouncing the name of God.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!